# How to recover data from a GPT protective partition?

Tags: data-recovery, gpt

Can I get IMAC data back from a WD1600SJ HDD which shows as GPT protective partition in Disk Management?

Answer (score 2):

Windows XP x64 was the first and only Windows XP edition that can recognize GPT partitions.  That being said, Windows XP x64, Vista or 7 do not understand HFS+ natively, you would need some software for that:

**Free solution:**
http://www.catacombae.org/hfsx.html

**Commercial solutions:**
http://www.mediafour.com/products/macdrive/
http://www.paragon-software.com/home/hfs-windows/

Reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463525#X-201104111922342

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using Windows XP?  Try Windows 7 or a Linux boot disc, both of which should be able to read GPT partition tables and disks.

What GPT does to prevent non-GPT disk-aware systems from reading it is to create a false partition on the MBR.  This marks the disk as used instead of free.  See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Legacy_MBR_.28LBA_0.29).